# What is the benefit of using SIMD to pre-calculate the branching results?

Tags: c++, llvm, simd

I noticed that for the following codes, the loop would be unrolled, and the results of eight consecutive (ident != -1) are computed with SIMD when compiled with LLVM. After that, the computed branching results are extracted one by one to do the branching. What is the benefit of using SIMD here when the number of branching is not reduced? It seems that it just turns the cmp instructions into the ``extractelement'' instructions.

```
struct T {
  short ident;
  int other_fields[10];
} ;

void foo(int n, struct T *data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        if (data[i].ident != -1)
            data[i].ident = 1;
}
```

The LLVM IR:

```
9:                                                ; preds = %66, %7
  %10 = phi i64 [ 0, %7 ], [ %67, %66 ]
  %11 = or i64 %10, 1
  %12 = or i64 %10, 2
  %13 = or i64 %10, 3
  %14 = or i64 %10, 4
  %15 = or i64 %10, 5
  %16 = or i64 %10, 6
  %17 = or i64 %10, 7
  %18 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %10
  %19 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %11
  %20 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %12
  %21 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %13
  %22 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %14
  %23 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %15
  %24 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %16
  %25 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.T, ptr %1, i64 %17
  %26 = load i16, ptr %18, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %27 = load i16, ptr %19, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %28 = load i16, ptr %20, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %29 = load i16, ptr %21, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %30 = load i16, ptr %22, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %31 = load i16, ptr %23, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %32 = load i16, ptr %24, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %33 = load i16, ptr %25, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %34 = insertelement <8 x i16> poison, i16 %26, i64 0
  %35 = insertelement <8 x i16> %34, i16 %27, i64 1
  %36 = insertelement <8 x i16> %35, i16 %28, i64 2
  %37 = insertelement <8 x i16> %36, i16 %29, i64 3
  %38 = insertelement <8 x i16> %37, i16 %30, i64 4
  %39 = insertelement <8 x i16> %38, i16 %31, i64 5
  %40 = insertelement <8 x i16> %39, i16 %32, i64 6
  %41 = insertelement <8 x i16> %40, i16 %33, i64 7
  %42 = icmp ne <8 x i16> %41, <i16 -1, i16 -1, i16 -1, i16 -1, i16 -1, i16 -1, i16 -1, i16 -1>
  %43 = extractelement <8 x i1> %42, i64 0
  br i1 %43, label %44, label %45

44:                                               ; preds = %9
  store i16 1, ptr %18, align 4, !tbaa !5
  br label %45
45:                                               ; preds = %44, %9
  %46 = extractelement <8 x i1> %42, i64 1
  br i1 %46, label %47, label %48

47:                                               ; preds = %45
  store i16 1, ptr %19, align 4, !tbaa !5
  br label %48

48:                                               ; preds = %47, %45
  %49 = extractelement <8 x i1> %42, i64 2
  br i1 %49, label %50, label %51

50:                                               ; preds = %48
  store i16 1, ptr %20, align 4, !tbaa !5
  br label %51

51:                                               ; preds = %50, %48
  %52 = extractelement <8 x i1> %42, i64 3
  br i1 %52, label %53, label %54

53:                                               ; preds = %51
  store i16 1, ptr %21, align 4, !tbaa !5
  br label %54

54:                                               ; preds = %53, %51
  %55 = extractelement <8 x i1> %42, i64 4
  br i1 %55, label %56, label %57

56:                                               ; preds = %54
  store i16 1, ptr %22, align 4, !tbaa !5
  br label %57
...
```

Comment: One thing I can think of is that doing all the memory fetches up front allows the CPU to do parallel memory fetches.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the generated assembly code too. I suspect there will be no actual branches in the final assembly just masked/blended SIMD instructions (which will prevent missed branch predictions which will be quite expensive). Maybe reading this article will help you https://en.algorithmica.org/hpc/simd/masking/

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have checked the generated code. There are still 8 branches in the assembly code.

Comment: Hmm, okay then I also do not quite know what's going on and why.

Comment: Checking multiple elements at once can be beneficial if it allows to skip multiple single comparison+assignments. This can be helpful if the condition is unlikely and the `.ident` elements where actually packed more closely. I doubt it helps here, but sometimes clang produces suboptimal code for SIMD-unfriendly code. Compare this with the SIMD-friendly `bar` function here: https://godbolt.org/z/exEYK1c7d

Comment: Looks like clang is just over-complicating things by manually gathering the `short` elements of different structs with `vpinsrw`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/47ffvn9eW).  I'd expect that to be slower than what GCC does, with higher latency to detect a mispredict.  Except that it has fewer loop branches so can get farther with fewer branches in the branch-order-buffer (48 entries on Skylake), but unrolling with scalar cmp+branch would have been better.  https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html#branches-in-flight

Comment: Your struct is so big that even AVX-512 masked stores would be doing one useful element per vector.  So this is a good use-case for the upcoming APX extension with `cfcmov` (conditionally-faulting CMOV) which can take a memory destination for a branchless scalar conditional store.  Or for 32-bit ARM predicated store.

Comment: Oh actually, a 512-bit vector is 16 `int`s, and these structs are only 11 `int`s in size, including padding for alignment.  So AVX-512 load, masked-compare into mask, and a masked store, could implement this if you unroll with 16 different masks and vectors to compare against and get a throughput of 16/11 structs per store (at maybe 1/clock).  But there are only 8 mask registers, and there isn't a `krot` mask-rotate instruction.  And  GPR `rol` plus `kmov` isn't great, nor is loading from an array of masks. Hmm, maybe sometimes use the low 16 of some masks, or `kshiftrd` to extract the high 16

Comment: Anyway, that's not what LLVM is doing.  If AVX-512 is available, it decides not to vectorize at all!!!   https://godbolt.org/z/4n6G7v8rd shows unrolled scalar asm for `-march=sapphirerapids` (unrolled by 8, vs. by 5 with `-march=x86-64-v4`)